# Magento 2 : Marketplace extension submission issue "Product is not compatible with Page Builder" error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, marketplace, page-builder

**I'm submitting my `Shipping tracker` module in the marketplace but they are giving me error as below,**

> Product is not compatible with Page Builder - Version 2.0.8 claims to
> be compatible with Page Builder, but the zip file does not support
> this claim

**This is the only message I got from the marketplace. Also, there is nothing related to page builder in my module**

**Let me know if anyone has any ideas.**

Comment: Have you got any solution? If you get a solution please share it here.

Comment: not yet @Msquare

Comment: Can you share your code here?

Comment: There is no code related to page builder

Answer (score 0):

Please Unselect page Builder Option.
this is available in below side. scroll **Technical Review**  page.